# Se puede unir 3 consultas en una sola en Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Hola soy nuevo en en base de datos (Mysql) Tengo que hacer 3 consultas en lo que intervienen 2 tablas Paciente - Sesiones

-Cantidad total pacientes CONDICION [Masculino - ID_etapa_vital1(0-3 años)]

-Cantidad total de sesiones (que tuvieron el total de paciente de la primera consulta)

-Cuantos fueron continuadores(continuadores significa que tuvieron mas de 5 sesiones tomando en cuenta igual la condicion de la primera consulta )

Hice las 2 primeras consultas de esta manera:

Edad 0-3 años

Cantidad total paciente

```
SELECT 
ID_Etapa_Vital ,count(*) 
FROM paciente 
WHERE Genero='Masculino' and ID_Etapa_Vital=1;
```

Cantidad Sesiones

```
SELECT 
Cantidad_sesiones ,count(*)  
FROM ong_padma.sesiones 
where ID_numero_historia in(
  SELECT ID_numero_historia 
  FROM paciente 
  WHERE Genero='Masculino' and ID_Etapa_Vital=1
);
```

Mi pregunta seria si se puede unir las 3 consultas en una sola y que me quede esta manera:

Ejemplo:

```
______________________________________________________________
|ID_Etapa_vital|Cantidad_total|Cantidad_sesiones|Continuadores|
| -------------| ------------ | --------------- | ------------|
|  1           |  50          |  100            | 20          |
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Procura compartir todo eso que muestras, como texto. Haces difícil que repliquemos tu situación porque nos toca transcribir todo de una imagen; como si te diéramos una respuesta en una imagen, te ponemos a transcribir código con la posibilidad de perder cosas en el camino. Y yo que ya voy rondando los 40, no veo casi nada en esas imágenes xD

Comment: La respuesta a tu pregunta actual sería **si, si se puede**. Supongo que no es lo que esperas, y esto es porque la pregunta está mal planteada. Te sugeiro comenzar por hacer el [tour] y leer [ask]. Luego, edita la pregunta, quita las imagenes y agrega **como texto** los datos de ejemplo y las consultas que has hecho hasta ahora. Toma en cuenta que este es un sitio donde se responden preguntas de programación, pero no se hace la tarea escolar ni se realizan requerimientos, por lo que no puedes plantear todo un problema. Es mejor que realices preguntas puntuales a medida que se presentan dudas

Comment: Ya va mejorando. Gracias. Ahora queda saber de dónde puede estar saliendo ese 30. Puede ser evidente pero nosotros no conocemos tu sistema. Es necesario entonces ver la estructura de las tablas sobre las que estás consultando y algún dato (falso o no) de prueba para ver de dónde quieres que salga el 30 :)

Comment: Puedes hacerlo usando `pivot` pero en mysql no está implementado sin embargo acá te explica como realizarlo: https://linuxhint.com/mysql_pivot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por la naturaleza de la información que quieres obtener, la primera manera que se me ocurre es realizar tres sub-consultas. De esta manera, la información saldrá como tu la quieres y la lógica, que es bastante dispar, se mantiene en cada una de las sub-consultas.
Además funcionaría en cualquier versión de mySQL y en muchos otros motores.

Voy a asumir que tienes una tabla de *etapas vitales*, y sobre esta haremos girar las sub-consultas.

Lo primero sería tener una consulta simple sobre la tabla de etapas vitales, por ejemplo:

```
select ID_Etapa_vital
  from EtapaVital
```

Luego, para poder integrar la consulta del número de pacientes, como una sub-consulta, necesitamos que esta devuelva únicamente el contador de pacientes y relacionarla con la tabla `EtapaVital`, quedaría de esta manera:

```
select   EtapaVital.ID_Etapa_vital
       , (select count(*) 
            from paciente 
           where paciente.Genero ='Masculino' 
             and paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital = EtapaVital.ID_Etapa_Vital
         ) NumeroDePacientesMasculinos
  from EtapaVital
```

De la misma manera habría que integrar la consulta del número de sesiones, pero antes de hacerlo, sugiero cambiar la forma de relacionar las tablas por un `inner join`, por ejemplo de esta manera:

```
select count(*)  
  from ong_padma.sesiones 
       inner join paciente on paciente.ID_numero_historia = sesiones.ID_numero_historia
 where paciente.Genero = 'Masculino'
   and paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital = 1
```

Así, integrado quedaría de esta manera:

```
select   EtapaVital.ID_Etapa_vital
       , (select count(*) 
            from paciente 
           where paciente.Genero ='Masculino' 
             and paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital = EtapaVital.ID_Etapa_Vital
         ) NumeroDePacientesMasculinos
       , (select count(*)  
            from ong_padma.sesiones 
                 inner join paciente on paciente.ID_numero_historia = sesiones.ID_numero_historia
           where paciente.Genero = 'Masculino'
             and paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital = EtapaVital.ID_Etapa_Vital
         ) NumeroDeSesionesConPacientesMasculinos
  from EtapaVital
 where EtapaVital.ID_Etapa_Vital = 1
```

En este último ejemplo, he agregado un `where` para quedarnos solamente con la etapa vital con ID 1, que es la que te interesa.

Así, podrías integrar cualquier número de consultas.

Antes de continuar, quisiera comentar que ver la relación que hay entre las tablas paciente y sesiones, por un campo que no es el `id` del paciente me llama la atención y no entiendo de donde viene. Si hay otra tabla que las relacione, creo que lo más claro es dejar esa tabla dentro del query y relacionar las entidades por su `id`. En cambio, si la relación es directa, lo que yo esperaría ver es algo como:

```
inner join paciente on paciente.ID_Paciente = sesiones.ID_Paciente
```

Diría que este es un indicador de que, al modelo, le falta algo de trabajo.

De la misma manera, que haya una mezcla de tablas con nombre en singular y en plural. Utiliza uno u otro, pero no ambos. Hay *corrientes filosóficas* que te dirán que las nombres en singular, otras en plural, pero ninguna te dirá que las mezcles.

Yo soy de los que las nombran en singular, y mis razones están fuera del alcance de esta pregunta. Simplemente, no las mezcles.

Finalmente, si utilizas mySQL 8.0 o superior y en algún momento necesitas la información de más de una etapa vital, obtendrías un mejor desempeño utilizando CTE's:

### MySQL 8.0 o superior

Acá, puedes valerte de los *CTE* para realizar cada consulta para varias etapas vitales y finalmente unir los resultados, por ejemplo, adaptar las consultas que ya teníamos antes para que nos devuelvan información agrupada por etapa:

```
with
TotalPacientes as (
select paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital, count(1) NumeroDePacientesMasculinos
  from paciente 
 where paciente.Genero ='Masculino' 
 group by paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital
)
,
TotalSesiones as (
select paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital, count(1) NumeroDeSesionesConPacientesMasculinos 
  from ong_padma.sesiones 
       inner join paciente on paciente.ID_numero_historia = sesiones.ID_numero_historia
 where paciente.Genero = 'Masculino'
 group by paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital
)
select   EtapaVital.ID_Etapa_Vital
       , TotalPacientes.NumeroDePacientesMasculinos
       , TotalSesiones.NumeroDeSesionesConPacientesMasculinos
  from EtapaVital
       left join TotalPacientes on TotalPacientes.ID_Etapa_Vital = EtapaVital.ID_Etapa_Vital
       left join TotalSesiones on TotalSesiones.ID_Etapa_Vital = EtapaVital.ID_Etapa_Vital
```

Considero que, al estudiar los ejemplos y comprender la mecánica, no tendrás dificultades para integrar tu tercera consulta al ejercicio.

Comment: Muchas gracias , eres un crack , estudiare la forma como lo hicistes te lo agradezco mucho...

Comment: @Paucar si resolvió tu duda, márcala como aceptada por favor